# Persistent reverse SSH tunnels

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

We have a number of servers (currently in the 10s, soon the low 100s) deployed to varying institutions with varying network layouts. To make sure that we can access the servers at will we have them setting up reverse SSH tunnels back to a server we have in "the cloud" solely for this purpose. To keep the connections open persistently the guys who set it up used autossh and have supervisor monitoring it. The problem we're experiencing is that periodically (and somewhat frequently) the connections will just close mid-use... as in, you can be actively typing and BAM `Connection to localhost closed.`

If anyone could help me sort out what I'd need to change to get the connections to be more stable, I'd greatly appreciate it. If you need to see any other config files, just ask.

The main supervisor config file looks like:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run//supervisor.sock
chmod=0700

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run//supervisor.sock

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

The supervisor config file specifically for the autossh is:

```
[program:autossh]
command=autossh -M29001 -f -N -R 10033:localhost:22 name@domain.com
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=KILL
```

Comment: Why haven't you looked at the logs?

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong way to do it. A VPN as per MikeyB's suggestion is almost certainly the right way.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get a much more reliable setup by doing it properly with an VPN server on your central jumpbox server and having the customer machines VPN into that server and get an IP.

Comment: When answering a question it would be nice to answer the same question, not another question that OP didn't ask for.

Answer (score 2):

I've had *IDLE* SSH tunnels time out regularly. To solve that, I pass -o "ServerAliveInterval=10" to ssh (which should also work with autossh). However, since you report that this can occur to an *active* SSH session, this may not actually fix your problem.